# How to use :before for the third <li> element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to add `>` before the third `<li>` element without adding new any classes or id's?

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5T3F/2/).

HTML:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb-tasks">
  <li>Ethernet</li>
  <li>Compputer</li>
  <li>Design</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```css
.breadcrumb-tasks{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.breadcrumb-tasks li {
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}

.breadcrumb-tasks li + li:before {
  color: #ccc;
  content: "/\00a0";
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p5T3F/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the old browsers which don't support [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo class you could use [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) as follows:

```css
.breadcrumb-tasks li + li + li:before {
    content: ">\00a0";
}
```

And override the `content` for **4th**, **5th**,... list items as:

```css
.breadcrumb-tasks li + li:before,           /* selects 2nd+ list items  */
.breadcrumb-tasks li + li + li +li:before { /* selects 4th+ list items  */
  color: #ccc;
  content: "/\00a0";
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/p5T3F/6/)**

But for modern browsers [support CSS3 selector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) (including IE9+):

```css
.breadcrumb-tasks li:nth-child(3):before {
    content: ">\00a0";
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/p5T3F/8/)**.

Answer (score 1):

This way, it is always the last one (if you have more than 3).

```
ol li:last-child:before{
    content: ">";
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mhk8S/)

Comment: Yep! Works perfectly! (I added a fiddle). Hope this helped! @Dj.Sunrise

Answer (score 0):

```
li:nth-child(3):before
{
    content: ">";
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/p5T3F/5/)**

Comment: I don't know =) I haven't reputation for voting

Answer (score 0):

```
.breadcrumb-tasks li:last-child:before { content: "› "; }
```